# Using a variable like an index of an array in logstash pipeline

Tags: ruby, logstash

I have this filter in a logstash pipeline

```
filter{

    ruby { code => 'event.set("patternmatch1", event.get("message").scan(/TEXT.*?(\w[\w,.]*)\r?$/))'
    }

    # Retrieve the lenght of the array cointaining all the matches
    ruby { code => 'event.set("number_of_elements", event.get("patternmatch4").length-1)'
    }
```

**My goal**

I would like to use the array length as the index of a ruby array of patterns to choose index pattern that i want. Instead of using index 9:

```
mutate{
       add_field => {"gross_profit" => "%{[patternmatch4][9]}"}}
}
```

I want to reference the last pattern matched in the array with the variable containing the lenght of the array "number_of_elements", but my code is not working. Maybe i am incorrectly referencing the variable. How to reference that variable correctly?

```
mutate{
   add_field => {"gross_profit" => "%{[patternmatch4][%{[number_of_elements]}"}}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below any one of the way,

Fetching a last index from the array,

```
ruby {
    code => 'event.set("gross_profit", event.get("patternmatch4")[-1])'
}
```

Specific to index pattern,

```
ruby{
  code => '
    number_of_elements = event.get("patternmatch4").length - 1
    event.set("number_of_elements", number_of_elements)
    event.set("gross_profit", event.get("patternmatch4")[number_of_elements])
  '
}
```

I got the answer from ELK forum, if you need speedy resolution please post your query in ELK forum. If you already got this answer from forum, just ignore it.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-a-variable-like-an-index-of-an-array-in-logstash-pipeline